# Comparing UIWindow and UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwindow

What are the differences between a `UIWindow` and a `UIView` in Objective-C?

How does the view hierarchy work? I know that you can add a `UIView` to a `UIWindow`, with something like:

```
[self.window addSubview:secondView];
```

Are you able to add a `Subview` to another `UIView`?

Comment: A `UIWindow` is a `UIView`. Look at the reference docs for both. It is `UIView` that has the `addSubview` method.

Comment: You should also read the [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [difference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503) between UIWindow and UIView.

> In iOS, you use windows and views to present your application’s content on the screen.Windows do not have any visible content themselves but provide a basic container for your application’s views. Views define a portion
>   of a window that you want to fill with some content. For example, you
>   might have views that display images, text, shapes, or some
>   combination thereof. You can also use views to organize and manage
>   other views.